# Some data is not getting scraped in Python Selenium, webscraping?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I am scraping booking.com and taking hotel name, ratings, hotel description, a number of reviews, ratings, address, category (check whether it is hotel or hostel) and locations.

**My questions:**

1) I was scraping 30 pages, and by the end, I got missing values in a number of reviews, ratings and category. When I went back and checked the site all the values are available for these fields. I am not sure why it's not capturing. Please advise?

2) There is no missing value if I scrape the individual page. What would be the reason?

```
#Importing necessary library

from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
import pandas as pd
import time
import re
import requests
from itertools import zip_longest
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

category = []
name = []
address = []
reviews = []
review_title = []
ratings = []
description = []
facilit = []

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
for pageno in range(0,750, 25): 
    print(pageno)
    #driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
    driver.get("https://www.booking.com/searchresults.en-gb.html?aid=397642&label=gog235jc-1FCAEoggI46AdIM1gDaK4BiAEBmAEJuAEXyAEM2AEB6AEB-AEMiAIBqAIDuALm3eDyBcACAQ&sid=422b3ff3c0e98b522259ad1cad2505ea&tmpl=searchresults&ac_click_type=b&ac_position=0&checkin_month=7&checkin_monthday=1&checkin_year=2020&checkout_month=7&checkout_monthday=15&checkout_year=2020&class_interval=1&dest_id=-1506909&dest_type=city&dtdisc=0&from_sf=1&group_adults=2&group_children=0&iata=AKL&inac=0&index_postcard=0&label_click=undef&no_rooms=1&postcard=0&raw_dest_type=city&room1=A%2CA&sb_price_type=total&search_selected=1&shw_aparth=1&slp_r_match=0&src=index&src_elem=sb&srpvid=0da61131394c0103&ss=Auckland%2C%20Auckland%20Region%2C%20New%20Zealand&ss_all=0&ss_raw=Auckland&ssb=empty&sshis=0&top_ufis=1&rows=25&offset=0" + str(pageno))
    time.sleep(1)

    summaryItems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[contains(@class, 'hotel_name_link url')]")
    job_links = [summaryItem.get_attribute("href") for summaryItem in summaryItems]

    for job_link in job_links:
        driver.get(job_link)
        time.sleep(1)

        try:
            job_title = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='hp__hotel-type-badge']").text
            category.append(job_title)
        except:
            job_title = "None"

        try:
            hotel = driver.find_element_by_id('hp_hotel_name').text.strip('Hotel')
            name.append(hotel)

        except:
            hotel = "None"

        try:
            add = driver.find_element_by_id('showMap2').find_element_by_class_name('hp_address_subtitle').text
            address.append(add)

        except:
            add = "None"

        try:
            reviews = driver.find_element_by_class_name('bui-review-score--end').find_element_by_class_name('bui-review-score__text').text
            review_title.append(reviews)


        except:
            reviews = "None"

        try:
            rating = driver.find_element_by_class_name('bui-review-score--end').find_element_by_class_name('bui-review-score__badge').text
            ratings.append(rating)


        except:
            rating = "None"

        try:
            desc = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='property_description_content']").text
            description.append(desc)


        except:
            rating = "None"

driver.close()


# Converting all the details into dataframe and csv file
final = []
for item in zip_longest(name, address, review_title, ratings, description, category):
    final.append(item)

df4 = pd.DataFrame(
    final, columns=['Hotel_name', 'Address', 'Number_of_review', 'Ratings', 'Description', 'Category' ])
#df.to_csv('booked.csv')
```

Comment: Please [edit the question](/posts/60445186/edit) to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: @DebanjanB corrected and updated the questions